# Having an issue animating certain elements UIView will excluding others

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiimageview, swift

In my code, I've correctly moved the UITextfield into view when the keyboard pops up. However, I've struggled to create another animation that acts only on the UIImageView as this current solution permanently offsets the logo in the UIImageView.

```
var logoImage:UIImageView!
var logoImageX:CGFloat = 85
var logoImageY:CGFloat = 35

// Logo Code

let logo:UIImage = UIImage(named:"color-logo.png")
let logoHeight:CGFloat = 150
let logoWidth:CGFloat = logoHeight

logoImage = UIImageView(image:Logo)
logoImage.frame = CGRectMake(logoImageX,logoImageY,logoWidth, logoHeight)
self.view.insertSubview(logoImage, atIndex: 1)

// Keyboard Auto Scroll

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    self.animateTextField(textField, up: true)
    self.animateWithDuration(true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    self.animateTextField(textField, up: false)
    self.animateWithDuration(false)
}

func animateTextField(textField:UITextField,up: Bool){

    let movementDistance:Int = -100
    let movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.25
    var movement = CGFloat(Int((up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance)))

    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context:nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}
```

Here's the function for the UIImageView:

```
//Logo (UIImageView) Scroll
func animateWithDuration(up:Bool){
    let logoMovementDuration = 0.25
    let logoMovementDistance:Int = 20
    var logoMovement = CGFloat(Int((up ? logoMovementDistance : -logoMovementDistance + (logoImageY))))
    UIView.beginAnimations("animateWithDuration", context:nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(logoMovementDuration)
    logoImage.frame = CGRectMake(logoImageX,logoMovement,logoImage.frame.size.width,logoImage.frame.size.height)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the block based animations? Apple has recommended against using the beginAnimations/commitAnimations methods ever since iOS 4.

Comment: I've only started developing since iOS 7 and I haven't noticed the push away from beginAnimations/commitAnimations methods. Do you believe that block based animations hold the key to my current conundrum?

Comment: You're right, going through the documentation I've found that Apple does recommend beginAnimation/commitAnimation for iOS 4.0 and below and animation blocks for all iOS versions since. I've found an answer and have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution by creating multiple UIViews, or in my case 3 specifically.

The code looks like this, depending on what you want to achieve, segregated into different groups in order to apply animations to each of them (these are declared outside of the viewDidLoad() to make them publicly accessible):

```
var otherView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var logoImageView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: xx, height: xx)) 
var resultView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: xx, height: xx))
```

After which, I added the subviews to UIView instances and then finally into the super view (declared within the viewDidLoad()):

```
self.logoImageView.insertSubview(logoImage, atIndex:1)
self.view.insertSubview(logoImageView, atIndex: 1)
```

Then finally applied the same func's now using the block based animations as suggested by [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar) and recommended by Apple since iOS 4.0 (outside of, and after, the viewDidLoad()):

// Keyboard Auto Scroll

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    self.animateTextField(textField, up: true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    self.animateTextField(textField, up: false)
}

func animateTextField(textField:UITextField,up: Bool){

    let resultMovementDistance:Int = -xx
    let movementDistance:Int = -xx
    let movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.xx
    var resultMovement = CGFloat(Int((up ? resultMovementDistance : -resultMovementDistance)))
    var otherMovement = CGFloat(Int((up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance)))
    var logoMovement = otherMovement/5
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        movementDuration,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations:{
        self.otherView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.otherView.frame,0,otherMovement)},
        completion:nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        movementDuration,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations:{
            self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.logoImageView.frame,0,logoMovement)},
        completion:nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        movementDuration,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations:{
            self.resultView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.resultView.frame,0,resultMovement)},
        completion:nil)
}
```

Note: I did struggle with nesting the animations in the block, but I'm glad that it worked out. I hope this helps.